# Need help understanding basic recursion problem

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I have just started practicing with recursion I have this very simple practice program problem.

There are bunnies standing in a line, numbered 1,2,3... The odd bunnies (1,2,3..) have normal 2 ears.

The even bunnies (2,4,6...) have 3 ears, because they each have a raised foot. Recursively return the number of ears in the bunny line.

I have the solution. However, I am a bit confused on certain things. For one, it is my understanding that each even numbered rabbit has 3 feet. So bunnyEars2(2), should produce 6 instead of 5?

Also, I notice if I remove certain intricacies like '(bunnyEars2(bunnies)' instead of adding in the '-1' at the end. I get this duplicitous message "at bunnyEarsTwo.bunnyEars2(bunnyEarsTwo.java:13).

Any explanation and breakdown of this problem and recursion in general is very much appreciated. I am determined to learn, I just want to be pointed in the right direction!

```
 public static int bunnyEars2(int bunnies){
    if(bunnies==0) return 0;
    return (bunnies % 2 == 0) ? (3+bunnyEars2(bunnies-1)) : (2+bunnyEars2(bunnies-1));
}
```

Comment: do you know factorial by recursive?

Comment: yes that one i manage to figure it out, i get the logic behind that one return num*factorial(num-1). Just this one i am finding it kind of diffucult to grasp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you know factorial by recursive. because this is very similar.

```
int factorial(int n){    
  if (n == 0)    
    return 1;    
  else    
    return(n * factorial(n-1));    
 }
```

Here we are returning `n * n-1 * n-1-1 * n-1-1-1 and so on until it n-1.... is 0.
Likewise,

```
public static int bunnyEars2(int bunnies){
    if(bunnies==0) 
        return 0;
    if (bunnies % 2 == 0)
        return  3+bunnyEars2(bunnies-1);
    else 
        return  2+bunnyEars2(bunnies-1);
}
```

Here, follows same logic, but the differece is , 
when its even, it return `3 + bunnyEars2(bunnies-1)` 
when its odd, it return `2 + bunnyEars2(bunnies-1)` 
for example: `bunnyEars2(4)` is `10`
here our bunnies value will be `4,3,2,1,0` 
as 4 is even it returns `3+`, 3 is odd it returns `2+`, 2 returns `3+`, 1 returns `2+` and 0 returns `0`
3 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 0 = 10.
`bunnyEars2(2)` will be `5`, here bunnies value will be `2,1,0` which returns `3 + 2 + 0 = 5`
Also removing `-1` from `bunnyEars2(bunnies-1)` will result in infinite recursion(stack overflow error). It's like removing `-1` from `n * factorial(n)`, it won't end.